# Python with Selenium Assertion Raises or Exception has never worked

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, exception, assertion

I have an issue with Selenium and Python. I don't know why either exceptions or Assertions that I include in my code are not taken. This mean that default exception/assertion behavior is follow instead of taking the behavior that I 've defined.

For instance, in the following case I want that when some element is not found the application displays a message and then the browser is closed. I removed the message because Selenium has never shown my messages , so , I 've kept the piece of code where I closed the browser, but it has just been shown Standard Error every time.
How can I define a custom exception or handle it with Assertion Raise?

```
con = set_up.Connect()
driver = con.setUp()

def element_fail(self): **#This function is never called**

    self.con.tearDown() **#I 've defined this piece of code in another                          #module but it is just self.driver.quit**

def test_login(self):

    #there is login but there is not user validation functionality.
    # So Basic login test cases without assert has been included
    try:

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) \
            .until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, "userName")))

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) \
            .until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))

        **WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) \
            .until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "nada")))**

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) \
            .until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "login")))

    **except TimeoutError:
        print("element not found")
        element fail() # same result if I use self.con.tearDown() instead #this blocked of code is never called, since my browser is not closed**
```

---

Response:

```
Testing started at 3:25 PM ...
/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/bin/python /home/osboxes/Desktop/Emi/pycharm-community-2018.1.3/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --path /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/unit_test/login.py
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/unit_test/login.py in /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/unit_test


Ran 1 test in 11.036s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/unit_test/login.py", line 32, in test_login
    **.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "nada")))**
  File "/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
**selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Process finished with exit code 1**
```

Comment: What do the ** mean ? Are those added afterwards ? I would not expect your catch to run because it raises a TimeoutException, not a TimeoutError.

Comment: What test executes in: unit_test/login.py", line 32, in test_login ?
This ;> .visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "nada"))) , it'e not visiable for some reason. Try to lacate it with differetn aproach, like XPATH ...

Comment: Sorry those "**" are not part of the code. Stack Overflow put them when I was trying to format my text. I know that ByName."nada"  is not working, in fact I put it there to test that some error is raised. My concern if why Python doesn´t take the error handle/behavior that I want to give it (e.g a custom print and continue) instead of the default one

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the issue. When I put an Expected Conditions in the middle of the code , I ´ve just caught some event but I haven´t done anything with that error. So, I´ve defined a function in this way:

```
import unittest
from selenium.common.exceptions import  NoSuchElementException
from connect import set_up
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class HomeLinks(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):

         con = set_up.Connect()
         self.driver = con.setUp()

     def test_home_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Home"), "Element is not found")
         self.home = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Home")


     def test_flight_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights"), "Element is not found")
         self.home = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Flights")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights")

     def test_destinations_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Destinations"), "Element is not found")
         self.destinations = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Destinations")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Destinations")

     def test_contact_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "CONTACT"), "Element is not found")
         self.contact = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("CONTACT")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "CONTACT")

     def test_signOn_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "SIGN-ON"), "Element is not found")
         self.sign_on = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("SIGN-ON")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "SIGN-ON")

     def test_register_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "REGISTER"), "Element is not found")
         self.register = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("REGISTER")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "REGISTER")

     def test_support_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "SUPPORT"), "Element is not found")
         self.support = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("SUPPORT")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "SUPPORT")

     def test_hotels_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Hotels"), "Element is not found")
         self.hotels = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Hotels")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Hotels")

     def test_carRentals_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Car Rentals"), "Element is not found")
         self.car_rentals = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Car Rentals")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Car Rentals")

     def test_cruises_link(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Cruises"), "Element is not found")
         self.cruises = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cruises")
         self._event_test(self.home, By.LINK_TEXT, "Cruises")

     def is_element_present(self, how, what):

         '''

         :param how: By Locator Type
         :param what: Locator value
         :return: Exception(if it is not found), otherwise, return True
         '''

         try:
             self.driver.find_element(how, what)

         except NoSuchElementException:
             return False
         return True

     def _event_test(self, element, how, what):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)\
         .until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((how, what)))
         element.click()
         self.driver.back()
```